# Generating type at runtime

Tags: c#-4.0, il

I need to create type with properties at runtime.
Type must be look like this:

```
public class RunTimeType : BaseType
{

private string _field1;

public string Property1
  {

     get { return _field1; }
     set
     {
        if (_field1 != value)
        {
           _field1 = value;
           OnAfterPropertySet("Property1");
        }
     }
  } 

}
```

the question is how to create Set method ? Now i use folowing code :

```
var propertyName = "Property1";

var onAfterPropertySet = baseType.GetMethod("OnAfterPropertySet",
                                              BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                                              BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(string) },
                                              null);


ILGenerator currSetIL = currSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);

currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, propertyName);
currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, onAfterPropertySet);
currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);

currSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

but when i trying to set value to the property, exception is thrown

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Generating IL is rarely the best solution.

Comment: i get TargetInvocationException

Comment: and inner exception is InvalidProgramException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really close.  You forgot the equality test and passing the hidden *this* argument to the instance method.  The best way to do this is to write the code in C# first:

```
class Test {
    private string _field1;
    private void OnAfterPropertySet(string arg) { }
    public string Property1 {
        set { 
            if (_field1 != value) {
                _field1 = value;
                OnAfterPropertySet("Property1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Build it in the Release mode then take a look at the generated IL with ildasm.exe or Reflector:

```
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldfld      string ConsoleApplication1.Test::_field1
  IL_0006:  ldarg.1
  IL_0007:  call       bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Inequality(string,
                                                                   string)
  IL_000c:  brfalse.s  IL_0020
  IL_000e:  ldarg.0
  IL_000f:  ldarg.1
  IL_0010:  stfld      string ConsoleApplication1.Test::_field1
  IL_0015:  ldarg.0
  IL_0016:  ldstr      "Property1"
  IL_001b:  call       instance void ConsoleApplication1.Test::OnAfterPropertySet(string)
  IL_0020:  ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Ldarg_0` before calling `onAfterPropertySet` for the `this` parameter.